# Python string initialisation ['Hello World'] and 'Hello 'World' differences

Tags: string, arrays

I started learning Python, version 3, and I tried the following code in the Interpreter

```
$ python3 
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr  9 2019, 04:59:38) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> Justring = 'Hello World' 
>>> Justring[2]
'l'
>>> Justring = ['Hello World']
>>> Justring[0]
'Hello World'
>>> Justring[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

What is the difference in the initialisation of the string Justring for these cases

['Hello World']

'Hello World'

Where can I get such explanations.

Comment: (There's [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is that square brackets indicate a list.

`[“hello world”]` is a list containing one string. So the first index is the entire string. The second index is out of range because there is only one item in the list.

Try again with `[“hello world”, “hello again”]` and you’ll see there is an additional valid index.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  I started studying six types of data. String, Lists, Dictionaries etc.  Thanks I will pick up.